# Лишняя информация в консоли VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

раньше пользовался VS Code для компиляции c++ кода, обычно это делалось на Линуксе и там не возникало таких проблем. К сожалению сейчас приходится работать на Виндовс (я студент) и я решил следовать этим инструкциям: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw Код компилируется, но в консоли кроме выводов, которые я описал в коде присутсвуют сторонние (скриншот прилагается). Как это можно исправить?
Я попробовал писать `system("cls");` в коде перед выводами, но это не увенчалось успехом.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]